# Android - ActionBar SearchView suggestions with a simple String array

Tags: android, android-actionbar, ormlite, searchview

I want to implement an ActionBar Search Widget with suggestions ability.
**I already have** a string array stored in my ORMLite database that I want to use for the suggestions.
How can I do this without creating loads of classes (Provider, Searchable...!)?

Comment: Craete your custom CursorAdapter populate it using MatrixCursor, and set the adapter to SearchView http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/SearchView.html#setSuggestionsAdapter(android.support.v4.widget.CursorAdapter), Let me know if this info was enough.

Comment: In the docs is says that there's a constructor like this `CursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor)`. I try to do this `new CursorAdapter(this, matrix)` with matrix being a MatrixCursor I created. But it's impossible to instantiate a CursorAdapter... ?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

It's a sample, I hope it can help you.

To implements more features in this cursor, eg. open activity when press in suggestion item, take a look on this http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/adding-custom-suggestions.html

```
 package com.roberto.android.thetracker.app;

 import android.database.MatrixCursor;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.provider.BaseColumns;
 import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
 import android.support.v4.view.MenuItemCompat;
 import android.support.v4.widget.CursorAdapter;
 import android.support.v4.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
 import android.support.v7.widget.SearchView;
 import android.view.Menu;
 import android.view.MenuInflater;

 public class CustomSearchFragment extends Fragment {

     private static final String[] SUGGESTIONS = {
             "Bauru", "Sao Paulo", "Rio de Janeiro",
             "Bahia", "Mato Grosso", "Minas Gerais",
             "Tocantins", "Rio Grande do Sul"
     };
     private SimpleCursorAdapter mAdapter;

     @Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

         final String[] from = new String[] {"cityName"};
         final int[] to = new int[] {android.R.id.text1};
         mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(),
                 android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                 null,
                 from,
                 to,
                 CursorAdapter.FLAG_REGISTER_CONTENT_OBSERVER);
     }

     @Override
     public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
         setHasOptionsMenu(true);
     }

     @Override
     public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
         super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
         inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
     }

     @Override
     public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
         super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
         final SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat
                 .getActionView(menu.findItem(R.id.action_search));
         searchView.setSuggestionsAdapter(mAdapter);
         searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);

         // Getting selected (clicked) item suggestion
         searchView.setOnSuggestionListener(new SearchView.OnSuggestionListener() {
             @Override
             public boolean onSuggestionClick(int position) {
                 Cursor cursor = (Cursor) mAdapter.getItem(position);
                 String txt = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("cityName"));
                 searchView.setQuery(txt, true);
                 return true;
             }

             @Override
             public boolean onSuggestionSelect(int position) {
                 // Your code here
                 return true;
             }
         });

         searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
             @Override
             public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s) {
                 return false;
             }

             @Override
             public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {
                 populateAdapter(s);
                 return false;
             }
         });
     }

     // You must implements your logic to get data using OrmLite
     private void populateAdapter(String query) {
         final MatrixCursor c = new MatrixCursor(new String[]{ BaseColumns._ID, "cityName" });
         for (int i=0; i<SUGGESTIONS.length; i++) {
             if (SUGGESTIONS[i].toLowerCase().startsWith(query.toLowerCase()))
                 c.addRow(new Object[] {i, SUGGESTIONS[i]});
         }
         mAdapter.changeCursor(c);
     }

 }
```

Comment: I implemented your code correctly, I got the history array from my ORMLite database, it all compiles with no errors. Except when I enter a character that is a start to a string in the database, nothing happens, and when I enter the second character I get `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`... I have no idea why...

Comment: Here : http://snipt.org/VCy7#expand  
I converted the String array to ArrayList so I can add to it later.

Comment: In your code, searchHistoryList changes the size according you edit the SearchView, eg.: First letter 'T', 3 results 'Ta...', 'Th...', 'Th...', Second letter 'h', 2 results: 'Th...' and 'Th...', do you got it?

Comment: searchHistoryList doesn't change... it's initialized once in onCreateOptionsMenu.

Comment: I think you meant the MatrixCursor that changes

Comment: You seems be right.. which line are you getting this Exception?

Comment: I think i fount it, change `int[] to = new int[] { 0, R.id.simpleListItemText };` to `int[] to = new int[] { R.id.simpleListItemText };`

Comment: Thanks, it's finally working ! But now when I click on the suggestion nothing happens... I guess I'll just look it up. Thanks again ;)

Comment: Hey, Can u tell me how can i get selected item string from suggestion adapter

Comment: Thanks for the example! One thing to mention that you also need to call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` after calling `adapter.changeCursor(cursor)` otherwise suggestion list might become out of sync.

Comment: Can add to onSuggestionClick(int position):
Cursor cursor = (Cursor) mAdapter.getItem(position);
String txt = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("cityName"));
searchView.setQuery(txt, true);  So after you select something in suggestions it will appear in searchView!

Comment: great solution!

Comment: what is from and to ? @betorcs

Comment: @hitesh-sarsava, `from` are cursor columns name and `to` are views id

Comment: @betorcs hey, It's working but when I enter the first character the data is not updated in the searchView. any idea why? as soon as i enter the 2nd character the suggestions of the first character becomes visible for a split second and gets replaced by the new suggestions. I tried adding the notifyDataSetChanged, but it didn't help.

Comment: @free_style when you enter the first character, is it trigging `onQueryTextChange`?

Comment: @betorcs yes..even adapter.changeCursor() is also getting triggered

Comment: @betorcs at last I found the issue, the default threshold of autocomplete textview is 2 characters that why it was not working for single character. I had to do this ((AutoCompleteTextView) searchView.findViewById(R.id.search_src_text)).setThreshold(1); to change the default threshold.

Comment: ok i used this code and i worked fine for me but there is a problem it shows suggestions when length of searchview is 2 when length is 1 it dont' show suggestions...

Comment: It is great, working perfectly but how can I customize the suggestion view. I tried a lot but not working

Answer (score 7):

Base on [betorcs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2585374/betorcs)'s answer **:**

you don't need to have

```
searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {...});
```

you can use this, instead of that

```
mAdapter.setFilterQueryProvider(new FilterQueryProvider() {
    @Override
    public Cursor runQuery(CharSequence constraint) {
        return populateAdapter((String) constraint);
    }
});
```

and on populateAdapter, Replace "return c;" with "mAdapter.changeCursor(c);"

```
private Cursor populateAdapter(String query) {
    .
    .
    .
    return c;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 private String getSuggestion(int position) {
        MatrixCursor cursor = (MatrixCursor) searchView.getSuggestionsAdapter().getCursor();
        String suggest1 = cursor.getString(position);


        return SUGGESTIONS[Integer.valueOf(suggest1)];
    }
```

Comment: While this code might answer the question you still might consider adding a few explanatory sentences as this increases the value of your answer for other users.