# How to search SqLite database using searchview and make the options clickable?

Tags: android, sqlite

I am making a hotel app where i have stored cities in the database.Now, i have a `searchview` in activity1. If i type a certain letter in the search, all cities(in the Database) having that letter should show up. And when the user clicks on the city, the user should be directed to another activity. I dont know how to implement `searchview` that can search the database. And then make the possible results clickable.

Comment: You can assume this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23658567/android-actionbar-searchview-suggestions-with-a-simple-string-array/23660529#23660529 as part of answer.

Comment: see `Searchview#setSuggestionsAdapter`

Answer (score 0):

You can usa an `AutoCompleteTextView` and add the cities to its adapter.

Or a simple `EditText` combined to a `ListView`:
- the `ListView` contains the cities
- the `EditText` has a `TextWatcher` and when you type letters it will filter the `ListView`.
Then on each item of your list add a `clickListener` to display your activity